# Can't enable dataBinding even after adding plugin 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

The build.gradle script (module) structure is:

```
plugin {
...
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
}

android {
...
buildTypes {
...
}
dataBinding {
enabled = true
}
}
```

If I try to sync my project I get:

```
Could not set unknown property 'enabled' for BuildType_Decorated{name=dataBinding}
```

And when I hover in bold **enable = true** instruction from dataBinding block:
**If you plan to use data binding in a Kotlin project, you should apply the kotlin-kapt plugin**

Why is that happening if I included the plugin above? Both AS and Kotlin plugins are up to date... Is there any difference between 'kotlin-kapt' and 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data binding in `build.gradle` should be like this:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/databinding)

Answer (score 0):

However it is not important to use that plugin to use data bind just do

android {  dataBinding { enabled = true}
Inside the android  brackets

Clean the project and then do sync